# Google Map-SDK: Polygon does not appear on Android device

Tags: javascript, dom, google-maps-api-3

I have an Xamarin Android application with WebView. Inside it I use google map sdk v3. This allow me to create a polygon on the map. Each click on google map will add a point into my polygon.

But, it works well on the Android Emulator, however, on a physical device, like the Samsung Galaxy Note 8, it does not work. It does not seem related only to this device. Because it does not work on a pixel either.

Please see the screenshots:

[Emulator screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0qzT.jpg)
[image: Emulator screen shot]

[Android Device screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl9hM.jpg)
[image: Android Device screen shot]

As you can see. On the emulator we see the polygon. While on the Android device this polygon is missing.

I tried to understand where the polygons were drawn in the DOM. I was able to trace the markers but not the polygons

I wondered what I could have missed.

```
// Here how is created the polygon on the map..
var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon
(
    {
        map: this.map,
            clickable: false,
            paths: new google.maps.MVCArray([path]),
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            fillColor: "#000000",
            fillOpacity: 0.3
    }
);

// Later in the javascript code I have something like this for register click event:
this.addMarkerListener = google.maps.event.addListener
(
    that.map, 
    'click', 
    function(clickEvent)
    {
            var index = path.length;
            path.insertAt(index, clickEvent.latLng);
    }
);
```

Comment: What are the coordinates of the polygon's path? Do you get any errors? What Android emulator did you run your app on? And to narrow down the issue can you please try creating a different polygon ( a simple one e.g. from Google's docs) and see if the issue persists on your Android devices regardless?

Comment: After further tests I realized that by setting HardwareAccelerated == true .. it works well. With HardwareAccelerated == false .. it does not work .. 

It seems to be a bug with GoogleMap because I use their URL directly in my Android WebView:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

Comment: I can use HardwareAccelerated == true but I need to take a screenshot. And the problem come back

Comment: The problem occurs regardless of the type of overlay.

Comment: I created an sandbox example that demonstrate the problem.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/6mudppywijjpisc/MyWebView.zip

It's a Xamarin Android project. If you change HardwareAccelerated to true at the top of the MainActivity.cs.. It will be fixed. But I am unable to take screenshot of a WebView with HardwareAccelerated == true.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Let me look at this and get back to you.

Comment: Okay so I've done some investigation on my end and it looks like this may be intended behavior after all. Note what these resources say about hardware acceleration and its influence on drawing and layers. [1](https://www.codevision.in/blog/what-is-hardware-acceleration-why-you-should-use-in-xamarin-application/) [2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel).